# Excel меняет точку на запятую

Tags: c#, excel

Когда я вставляю в ячейку текст через

```
Excel.Range to = ...
to.Cells[1, 1].Value = "43.64";
```

То по непонятной причине вставляется 43,64.

При этом, если я вставляю что-то вроде 43.64.78, то точки на запятые не меняются.

Формат ячеек ставил и обычный и текстовый, разницы нет.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет ошибки. в *VBA* разделитель целой и дробной части - точка, на листе Excel в русской локали - запятая. При вставке на лист числа разделитель автоматически преобразуется в нужный.

Значение типа *43.64.78* - текст, в нем нет разделителя числовых данных, точка - часть текста, поэтому при вставке на лист символы не подменяются.

Если в данных, которые могут быть преобразованы, точки нужно сохранить, вставлять данные как текстовые (апостроф слева, лишний пробел...) или изначально задать формат столбца текстовым.

```
 to.Cells[1, 1].Value = "'43.64";
```

апостроф слева сигнализирует, что после него текст. В ячейке апостроф не отображается.